# What's a word for the exact opposite of regret?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, antonyms

I know you can say you were "super glad you did something," but I'm looking for a word that expresses this in nominal form, i.e. the opposite of "my biggest regret." (my biggest ___ ) Does a word like this exist?

Comment: You might like to clarify exactly which meaning of regret you're seeking an opposite for. Also it might help to expand your sample sentence to include a little more context.

Comment: This is all a matter of a pinion.

Comment: I would nominate "finest choice"

Comment: Opposites are always contextual. The opposite of "man" could be "machine", "woman", "monster", "animal", "boy", ... Similarly, you could be trying to express other kinds of regret. If I make a really bad gamble but end up winning against all odds through pure luck, I don't regret the outcome (since I won), but I wouldn't particularly do it again or think that I made the right choice by gambling. Conversely, if I lost against all odds on a good gamble, I could regret the outcome even though I don't regret choosing to engage the in the good gamble. That's a different type of regret.

Answer (score 50):

In the most general sense, the opposite of regretting something is to be *proud* of it.

To extend this further, the opposite of your ***biggest regret*** is your ***proudest moment***.

Comment: Good answer. +1 A reference or two might be worth thinking about.

Comment: *Regret* means you're sorry you did it. *Proudest moment* doesn't mean you're "super glad" you did it.

Comment: +1, but note that a regret needn't be a single moment -- ["my biggest regret is that I never \[...\]"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22my+biggest+regret+is+that+I+never%22) -- and a source of pride needn't be a single moment, either: ["what I'm most proud of is that I never \[...\]"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22what+I%27m+most+proud+of+is+that+I+never%22). So "proudest moment" works in many cases, but not all.

Comment: The opposite of "proudest" would be "most shameful". That's very different from "regret", even though you can feel shame over some of your regrets. Pride and shame are about how you perceive yourself, they're not really about some action or choice itself in the way regrets are. If you're talking about a moment, pride would roughly be "I am good because of what I did or found out in that moment", shame would be "I am bad because ...", but regret is "that choice was bad", not "I am bad".

Comment: @RichardKayser Just saying "X doesn't mean Y" is probably not all that helpful. Anyone who knows this already wouldn't need to be told that and anyone who doesn't would probably need the difference explained.

Comment: Agreed with @NotThatGuy - I think of pride as most directly an antonym of embarrassment or shame rather than regret.

Answer (score 38):

I would say the opposite of 'biggest regret' is 'greatest **satisfaction**'.

Regret is what is felt if one is dissatisfied with an outcome.

Satisfaction is the feeling of achievement, of success.

> 2a: **fulfillment of a need or want**
> b: the quality or state of being satisfied : CONTENTMENT
> c: a source or means of enjoyment : GRATIFICATION

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/satisfaction)

As noted in comment, the wording 'greatest satisfaction' accommodates to the OP's idiomatic wording 'biggest regret'. 'Big' is a matter of bulk, of burden.

'Great' is a matter of expansiveness, fulness, release.

> *This is the greatest satisfaction of my life* - Shakira, UNICEF Ambassador.

[Financial Times Interview](https://www.ft.com/content/c34d39f6-0c92-11e2-a73c-00144feabdc0)

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that “biggest satisfaction” sounds wrong. Probably want “greatest satisfaction.” No idea why, but personally I feel pretty strongly about that.

Comment: @KRyan Yes, the OP is borrowing 'biggest' from the idiomatic expression 'biggest regret'.

Comment: Oh yes, I definitely understand why that’s in the question—I just think that this *answer* (which is great and I definitely agree) should mention that the example sentence won’t work strictly as-is. (Noting that “greatest regret” does work might also be worthwhile, in case that parallelism is being sought.)

Comment: Big difference is that "regret" is a feeling of disliking the results of one's own choices, whereas "satisfaction" is a feeling of liking the results of choices that may be either one's own or someone else's (or even just random chance).  "Self-satisfaction" is a closer match, but still sounds awkward in the given context.

Comment: *Regret* means you're sorry you did it. *Satisfaction* doesn't mean you're "super glad" you did it.

Comment: Often there is no *perfect* antonym. Satisfaction can be a feeling that you have when you have been provided with something that you liked. A good meal gives you a feeling of satisfaction, and that sense of the word is not the antonym. However, satisfaction is also what you feel when you feel good about something you have done, and saying "one's greatest satisfaction" specifically picks out that sense of the word. And that sense is the antonym. It is like "regret" is Hong Kong and "satisfaction" is Argentina, which contains the opposite of Hong Kong but  more as well. And that's OK.

Comment: There is no exact antonym for regret as used in this example. There just isn't. So you find something close and use that.

Answer (score 19):

Three words come to mind.

1. Delight;
2. Joy;
3. Satisfaction.

---

One phrase, which is not the exact opposite but is commonly spoken, is ‘My greatest *achievement* is ...’

Comment: I think this is the usage that the OP is getting at. The "opposite" desired is of the individual actions, rather than states or the feeling _per se_.

Comment: *Regret* means you're sorry you did it. None of these words mean you're "super glad" you did it.

Comment: @RichardKayser: Not necessarily. It can also mean you’re sorry you did *not* do it. The words listed above can be used in different ways to arrive at the meaning that you are glad that you did (or did not) do it. For that same reason I mentioned that ‘achievement’ phrase at the end.

Comment: @displayName  I agree re sorry about not doing it. Re *achievement*, I get it, but IMHO it doesn’t address the OP’s desire for a noun version of “super glad you did something.”

Comment: @RichardKayser: I think I got what you mean. Regret is an extreme emotion. The ones I listed... 'Delight, 'Joy'... are more on the equanimous side. The words on the other end of the spectrum would be 'thrilled', 'exhilarated', 'overjoyed', gleeful', 'excited', 'animated', 'ecstatic', 'euphoric', rapturous', 'on cloud nine', 'in seventh heaven'. Maybe even 'hysterical', 'frenzied', 'blissed out', 'on a high', 'over the moon'.

Comment: @displayName Try those in “my biggest ______.” They’re not even nouns.

Comment: @Richard Kayser: I often regret things I didn't do, and quite often things that I had nothing to do with at all.

Comment: @displayName "It can also mean you’re sorry you did not do it." Great insight. I regret things I didn't do on a much deeper level than things I have done (e.g., I regret never telling that person how I feel). English doesn't require words to have mirror images. "My biggest joy" (better "my greatest joy") comes close to expressing non-regret in doing or not doing something. As far as feeling "gladness"... "My biggest gladness was..." hmmmmm, something inherently awkward about that...have you actually used that Richard?

Answer (score 12):

From the definition of [*regret*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regret):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1 a** : to mourn the loss or death of
> **1 b** : to miss very much
> **2** : to be very sorry for
>     // *regrets* his mistakes

And:

> It was my biggest *regret*.

---

In contrast (and with respect to "super glad you did something"), I think of [**delight**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delight):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1** : a high degree of gratification or pleasure : JOY
>     // children squealing in *delight*
> *also* : extreme satisfaction
>     // seems to take *delight* in the misfortunes of others
> **2** : something that gives great pleasure
>     // her performance was a *delight*

Although it can be used with *biggest*, it's more natural when paired with *greatest*:

> It was my *greatest* ***delight***.

From the definition, *gratification*, *joy*, *satisfaction*, and *pleasure* could also be used—but *delight* seems to encompass all those senses in a way that the others don't.

---

In fact, according to [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=biggest%20regret%2Cgreatest%20regret%2Cbiggest%20delight%2Cgreatest%20delight&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbiggest%20regret%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreatest%20regret%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbiggest%20delight%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreatest%20delight%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbiggest%20regret%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreatest%20regret%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbiggest%20delight%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreatest%20delight%3B%2Cc0), even *regret* is more commonly paired with *greatest*:

[image: biggest versus greatest (delight and regret)]

Comment: Did you mean it is less commonly paired?

Comment: No. *Regret* (as with *delight*) is **more** commonly paired with *greatest*. As the graph shows. The use of *biggest* is less common.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought you were comparing “greatest regret” and “greatest delight.”

Comment: I don't think delight really works.  It's usually an immediate emotion, while regret is something generally felt in retrospect.

Comment: *Regret* means you're sorry you did it. *Delight* doesn't mean to me that you're "super glad" you did it.

Answer (score 8):

When we express our "biggest regret" it refers to an action (or, inaction) on our part which had regrettable results. Therefore, the best way to express the opposite *result*, would be: ***My biggest triumph***.

Comment: *Regret* means you're sorry you did it. *Triumph* doesn't mean you're "super glad" you did it.

Comment: Yeah well, *"My biggest super glad,"* is hard to understand.

Answer (score 5):

***Regret*** expresses the notion that a prior decision or action turned out to be wrong, or would have been done differently if you had the knowledge you had today - it seemed good in the beginning, but turned out to be bad in the end. A word that captures dual aspects of the opposite of this is ***vindication***, which indicates that a previous action or belief turned out to be correct or justified, after a period of doubt - it seemed bad in the beginning (at least to some), but turned out to be good in the end.

> His investment in Enron turned out to be regrettable, but his early
> investment in Google was vindicated.

As pointed out in the comments, vindication requires a some sense of doubt, uncertainty, or opposition in the early stages, so it doesn't capture the general idea of "something you're glad you did", as it doesn't really apply if everyone agrees it was a good idea in the first place.

Comment: To me, this only really applies if the choice was seen in a negative light at the time but proved fruitful in the long run.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I agree, something that everyone expects to work in the first place probably isn't well-described as vindication. I think this fits even better as an opposite of regret, though, since a regret is something that seems good in the beginning but is bad in the end, while something that's vindicated seems bad in the beginning (to some) but is good in the end. It doesn't capture the generalized notion of "something you're glad you did", though.

Comment: *Regret* means you're sorry you did it. *Vindication* doesn't mean you're "super glad" you did it.

Comment: @RichardKayser Vindication means that the decision turned out to be the correct one in a rather objective sense, so it does lack some of the emotional component of "super glad". But I don't see how one could be anything but satisfied with a previous action that's later vindicated. It's not possible to regret an action that's vindicated, nor vindicate an action and still regret it - they are mutually exclusive, and express opposite sentiments about prior actions. A regrettable action was bad (you are unhappy you did it), a vindicated action was good (you are happy you did it).

Answer (score 4):

I feel like the main component of regret is that one *thinks about the past often and wishes it could be different*.  So we want a word/phrase that implies *thinks about the past often and is happy with how it went*.

So I propose:

[*fondness*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fondness) - "my fondest memory" or "I look back with great fondness"

Similar to that would be:

[*tenderness*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tenderness) - "I look back with great tenderness"

Comment: *Regret* means you're sorry you did it. Neither of these words mean you're "super glad" you did it.

Comment: @RichardKayser - You're not exactly putting up a true dichotomy with this objection (to every answers here I might add). Your _suggestion_ of "super glad" as a measure of the opposite of _regret_ isn't really justified - because you can also regret _not doing something_ - the opposite then doesn't mean you are at all glad (you could be quite neutrally _assured_ or _content_ for e.g.).

Answer (score 4):

I think the word you are after is **[achievement](https://www.google.com/search?q=achievement)**:

> noun: achievement; plural noun: achievements
>
> 1. a thing done successfully, typically by effort, courage, or skill.
>    "to reach this stage is a great achievement"

So you would say something like *Completing that project was my biggest achievement at the company.*

Comment: *Regret* means you're sorry you did it. *Achievement* doesn't mean you're "super glad" you did it.

Comment: @RichardKayser actually... it kinda does. If you hear someone say “my greatest achievement was xyz” you can be pretty sure that they’re “super glad” they did xyz. Achievement is maybe not the opposite of Regret, but the terms “greatest achievement” and “biggest regret” are pretty diametric. It misses slightly in that (as pointed out elsewhere) “my biggest regret was not doing xyz” is pretty common and it would be surprising to hear someone say “my biggest achievement was not doing xyz” but not necessarily - “my biggest achievement was staying sober for 20 years”...

Answer (score 2):

How about “contentment”? Regret is when you missed so the opposite would be you are content about something you achieved.

Comment: Do people talk about "my biggest contentment"?

Comment: *Regret* means you're sorry you did it. *Contentment* doesn't mean you're "super glad" you did it.

Answer (score 2):

Achievement or maybe accomplishment?  Possibly fondest memory as well.  I think a lot of it depends on the rest of the context.

Answer (score 2):

To regret is to 're-greet', meaning revisit and pore over the decision again and again. The opposite of that suggests completion and moving forward positively, so I'd suggest [**accomplishment**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/accomplishment?s=t).

Answer (score 2):

If **regret** conveys the state of mind *I wish I had done it*,

- one contrary is *I do not wish I had done it*: **relief**  and synonyms
- another one is  *I do wish I hadn't done it*: **remorse** and synonyms
- another one is *I do not wish I hadn't done it*: **satisfaction**  and synonyms

Depends on what one means for "exact contrary".

Not a mother tongue, though. Some of this logic might be unidiomatic, but the relationship between a state of mind in the present and an event in the past gives room to different nuances.

Answer (score 1):

As a single word request, I am unaware of any direct answer to your question where a word could swap regret in " my biggest regret is".

If you think about it, it makes sense that there is no single word antonym for regret, as regret is an emotion, and not all emotions (especially complex ones like regret) have a direct opposite.

If you regret something, that is just how you feel about it, you feel regret.

But to say that something is your biggest [opposite of regret] could mean a few things:

1. You're very glad that you did it.
2. You are very proud that you did it.
3. You feel very satisfied that you did it, etc.

Therefore, English speakers explain in more detail when they are talking about past events, they specify if they're proud of the event, or if it was a defining moment in their life, etc.

I have personally never felt the need for such a single word because in context there is usually more I want to say about the event, like the aforementioned feelings about it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that **regret** is describing the negative reaction or aversion to the consequences of an action taken in the past, then an exact opposite word would be **conviction** which is a positive reaction of validation to the consequences of an action taken in the past.

> **Conviction** - *noun* - a strong belief that is not likely to change, or
> the strong feeling that your beliefs are right:

[[Source: Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/conviction)]

Answer (score 0):

How about **gladness**, which is the noun form of **glad**. From Lexico:

**[glad](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/glad)**: Pleased; delighted.

Your example:

> My *biggest* **gladness** OR my *greatest* **gladness**.

I prefer the latter.

**Gladness** captures the nominal form of your "super glad" in a way other words don't. It's also the exact opposite of *regret* in the context of your question.

Comment: *Regret* means you're sorry you did it. *Gladness* doesn't mean you're "super glad you did it". It just describes a feeling of happiness. Gladness refers to the feeling itself, not to the thing that induces the feeling, so "my greatest gladness" is a poetic and non-standard grammatical usage. Even if you (incorrectly) use it this way, it doesn't capture any aspect of time or relationship to the past. For example, "my dog is my greatest gladness" just means your dog makes you happy, but does not indicate anything about your past feelings about your dog. Regret requires a time component.

Answer (score 0):

'My biggest **satisfaction** seems to fit well. Having regret means you are sorry it happened. Having satisfaction means you are glad it happened.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised *happiness* hasn't been volunteered? My greatest happiness, the great happiness of my life was et cetera. Regarding something as a happiness seems to be the opposite of regretting something. I dunno, it's odd there seems to be no obvious antonym.